# The linear group ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is absolutely irreducible

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime, $\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite field of order $q$ of characteristic $p$, and $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ a fixed algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $\rho:G\to {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be a representation of a group $G$. My question is the following:

**Question:** Suppose that $n\geq 2$ and $p\geq 5$. Suppose also that the image of $\rho$ is ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Then is it true that $\rho$ is absolutely irreducible? (i.e. irreducible over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$.)

It is true for $n=2$: If $\rho$ is not absolutely irreducible, then it is conjugate over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ to a representation that is upper triangular which implies the image of $\rho$ is solvable. But ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is not solvable if $p\geq 5$.

I think the answer to the question is yes for any $n\geq 2$. It would be great if someone could point out a reference.

Comment: I'm not following your proof for $n = 2$. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but the matrix $((1, 1), (0, 1))$ lives in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and is $p$-torsion in this group; does it not define a (necessarily reducible) representation $C_p \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Comment: But the image of your representation doesn't contains $SL_2$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. In that case, it suffices to consider the 'identity representation' of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, right?